# LazyImageLoading into RecyclerView + saving LoadedImages to database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-viewholder

The problem is as it is stated in question title. In fact I want to load images which I have their url in my records into `RecyclerView` and at the same time persist downloaded image to database. I am using `realm.io` and `Glide` and my `RecyclerViewAdapter` is as below:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ProductModel obj = getData().get(position);
    holder.data = obj;
    holder.title.setText(obj.getTitle());
    if (obj.getImage() == null) {

        Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(obj.getImageUrl())
            .fitCenter()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.bronteel_logo)
            .into(new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(holder.icon) {
            @Override
            protected void setResource(GlideDrawable resource) {
                // this.getView().setImageDrawable(resource); is about to be called
                super.setResource(resource);
                // here you can be sure it's already set
                ((ProductsFragment) mFragment).saveImage(obj, resource);
            }
        });

    } else {
        byte[] data = obj.getImage();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inMutable = true;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    }
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView title;
    public ImageView icon;
    public ProductModel data;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (data.getImage() != null)
            activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, ProductActivity.class).putExtra("id", data.getId()));
    }
}
```

And here's how I save images:

```
public void saveImage(final ProductModel data, Drawable drw) {
    new AsyncImagePersister(data).execute(drw);
}

private class AsyncImagePersister extends AsyncTask<Drawable, Void, byte[]> {
        private final ProductModel data;
        AsyncImagePersister(ProductModel data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(Drawable... drawables) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bmp = drawableToBitmap(drawables[0]);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            return stream.toByteArray();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final byte[] bytes) {
            super.onPostExecute(bytes);
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    data.setImage(bytes);
                }
            });
        }

        public Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
                if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
                    return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                }
            }

            if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            }

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        }
    }
```

However, when loading the images for the first time from internet (using Glide) it shows wrong pictures for different places and on the other hand after it fetches all images, the saved images to realm are in their correct place.

So what am I doing wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misplaced images is due to views are being recycled, So the loaded bitmap does not necessarily belong to the current position, And another thing to consider is that using **AsyncTask** inside a **RecyclerView** won't play nice and will cause lags in your UI, And for the final point, saving the byte[] array in your model might end up to a OOM exception!

If you want do some long running task inside your adapter, think of using a **Service**, **IntentService** or **ThreadHandler**, so you will be sending tasks one by one and the'd be queued and executed one by one.

About having offline access to images:
One option could be using **Glide.diskCacheStrategy** method and use **DiskCacheStrategy.ALL** so the original image size will be cached and you can use later in offline mode

Second option is to use **Picasso** instead of **Glide**!
so that you can use a custom **RequestHandler** and download the image and save it somewhere so you can access it later, consider memory management is all on your side and you should handle it!

here's a hint for your second option:
create class which extends from RequestHandler:

```
CustomReqHandler : RequestHandler() {
```

Then you should override two methods: **canHandleRequest()**, **load()**

in **canHandleRequest()** you should determine whether you want to handle current request or not, so define a custom scheme for these requests and check if this is one of them like:

```
val scheme:String = data.uri.scheme
```

the 2nd method is **load()** which is executed on a background thread and returns a **Result** object, download the image, save it somewhere, and return **Result** object!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to save the loaded images in your database when you're using `Glide` for this purpose. Glide caches the images loaded once automatically and efficiently. The caching is a complex system and if you want to read more about the caching with Glide, you might have a look [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-caching-basics).

Now, about the images loaded in wrong place - this should not happen. I found no serious bug in your `onBindViewHolder` but hence as I suggest you not to save the images locally you might consider loading the images simply with Glide like this.

```
Glide
    .with(context)
    .load(obj.getImageUrl())
    .fitCenter()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.bronteel_logo)
    .into(holder.icon);
```

Just you need to make sure if the `obj.getImageUrl()` is returning proper url.

Comment: I need to save them in database because I need to load them offline in other parts of my application. So I can't rely on catching. If you've got any idea how should I do it I'll appreciate your help. Otherwise I knew about catching options.